# I can't access Apple Font Tools via the terminal

Tags: macos, mac, fonts

I have a situation where I need to edit a given font. but after installing font tools on mac os mojave, and enter these commands on the terminal : `"ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf"` The command is not found.

I'm quite new to Apple and mac excuse me if this question is kind of silly.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@thetrevorharmon/how-to-use-apples-font-tools-to-tweak-a-font-a386600255ae) tutorial, and open my "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin..." folders to check for the binaries but didn't find the ftxdumperfuser binary anywhere.

Please does anyone know how to solve this and edit fonts ?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I got it working right now is to:

- Download the font tools package from Apple. Found them at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=font, picked the one for XCode 11.
- Mount the dmg file
- Enter the disk image `cd /Volumes/macOS\ Font\ Tools`
- Extract the package to a folder of your choosing: `pkgutil --expand-full macOS\ Font\ Tools.pkg ~/font-tools`
- The CLI tools are now available in `~/font-tools/FontCommandLineTools.pkg/Payload`, you may add the folder to your path, or copy the utils to your bin folder.